# Python: NULL bytes or control characters

Tags: python, lxml

I'm currently working with lxml. I'm setting attributes, and I get the following error:

> ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no
>   NULL bytes or control characters

I used the same script for some years, and I haven't had any problem till now (I've got new files to process).

How can I handle null bytes or control chars? The best solution probably is to ignore them. But how can this be done?

I set new strings like this:

```
w.set("lem", newString)
```

With the help of Jack, I know that the following causes the error:

> "Bad string is: 'Bo\xdf'".

How can I handle such cases?

Edit:
Using this function:

```
from curses import ascii
def clean(text):
    return str(''.join(
            ascii.isprint(c) and c or '?' for c in text
            ))
```

I don't get any error anymore. But the code sets a lot of "?". In place of the "?", I'd like to have the correct chars (in utf-8)...

Comment: This is probably because of certain charachters cannot appear in xml. Could you give an example of the `newString` you are trying to set.

Comment: The reason XML parsers are strict about this is precisely to prevent sloppy "I want to just ignore this problem" solutions. The proper fix is to find out what those disallowed characters are, what or who put them there, and how to prevent that from happening ever again.

Comment: (Granted, the error messages you get could often be more useful in pointing out what exactly is wrong.)

Comment: It appears your string is a byte string and not a Unicode string. Is it possible that the `\xdf` is the `ß` character? If so you should try decoding it with code page [`windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Indeed it is! :) But, using newString.decode("Windows-1252") does not work, either :(

Comment: Did you try `newString = newString.decode("windows-1252")`? None of the string methods work in-place, they all return a modified copy.

Comment: Ouw - I didn't know this. Thanks a lot! But, unfortunately, this doesn't work either :( What about simple replacements?

Comment: I re-edited my question again ;)

Comment: It works now. I just ignore such special cases (which are few ;) ). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm curious, what problems were remaining after my last suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To debug your problem, temporarily modify your code like this:

```
try:
  w.set("lem", newString")
except ValueError:
  print("Bad string is: "+newString)
```

and then you can see what the string is and figure out what is wrong and what to do about it.

Comment: I'd use `repr(newString)` for the error message so you can get hex values for the non-printable characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With this hint, I could see the following: "Bad string is: 'Bo\xdf'". How can I handle this case (and all other, comparable cases)? Thanks for any help! :)